# PyCharm by JetBrains installation

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to install the **PyCharm** IDE by JetBrains for Python (free community edition).

I managed to [download the PyCharm community version](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/download_thanks.jsp?edition=comm&os=linux), but I do not know how to install it. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

<sub>**Note:** This answer got updated in January 2019 according to JetBrains' recommendations at that time and because GetDeb seems broken. To see my previous version of the answer, check the [revisions](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/701656/5).</sub>

You can visit the [PyCharm Download page for Linux](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=linux).

They offer **three different ways** to install PyCharm (Professional or Community Edition) there, in order of my personal preference. Decide on one of them:

### JetBrains Toolbox App:

Don't download PyCharm directly, but instead get and install the free Toolbox App to manage all of your JetBrains IDEs easily. The Toolbox lets you conveniently manage and install all JetBrains IDEs and update them with a single click, all in one place. It can also centrally manage your account login, if you have a paid license.

I would strongly recommend it, especially if you might want to use any other JetBrains IDEs like e.g. IntelliJ or WebStorm too. This method also doesn't need administrator rights, everything will be installed in your home directory (`~/.local/share/JetBrains` by default).

To go this way, [download the Toolbox installer](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/) first. It comes as `.tar.gz` archive again, but only contains a single AppImage executable. Extract and run that to install the Toolbox. You can delete the downloaded archive and AppImage after that again. Then, launch the Toolbox App:

[image: Toolbox screenshot]

It will list your installed IDEs, and show all other available products below that. Just click the <kbd>Install</kbd> button next to the PyCharm edition you want (free Community or paid Professional) and it will do everything for you in background.

You should also probably check the Toolbox settings and adapt them to your preference. To do that, click the screw nut symbol in the top right corner. Most importantly in my opinion, decide if you want it to keep the previous version after an update as fallback. Note that each IDE will take roughly around 1GB disk storage, and if you have many IDEs installed and also keep fallback versions, this can add up to a lot of space if your Ubuntu partition isn't that big. You can also switch automatic Toolbox (not IDE) updates, Toolbox autostart and sending anonymous statistics on or off.

### Install as snap package:

JetBrains offers all PyCharm editions as snap packages for Ubuntu. This should be supported since 16.04. Some flavours of Ubuntu (like Lubuntu) might not come with snap support preinstalled though. Check [this installation guide](https://docs.snapcraft.io/installing-snap-on-ubuntu/6740) in that case.

I have not personally tried this approach, but it looks like a good thing to me.

Installing a PyCharm snap should be as simple as running one of the below commands, depending on which edition you want:

- ```
  sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic
  ```
- ```
  sudo snap install pycharm-professional --classic
  ```
- ```
  sudo snap install pycharm-educational --classic
  ```

Next, run either `pycharm-community`, `pycharm-professional`, or `pycharm-educational` in the terminal, depending on which you installed.

### Download as `.tar.gz` archive:

You can select and download an archive containing either the Professional or Community Edition from the page linked above.

This method should probably work on any system, but I would **personally not really recommended it** as you have to manually extract it somewhere and updates are also not that easy.

If you decide to go for this anyway, follow the instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/install-and-set-up-pycharm.html#install-PyCharm) after you downloaded the `.tar.gz` archive file for your preferred edition. For your convenience, here's an **adapted version** of the official instructions:

> 1. Unpack the `pycharm-*.tar.gz` file to the folder where you want to install PyCharm:
>
>    ```
>    tar xfz pycharm-*.tar.gz -C <new_archive_folder>
>    ```
>
>    The recommended installation location according to the filesystem hierarchy standard (FHS) is `/opt`. To install PyCharm into this directory, enter the following command:
>
>    ```
>    sudo tar xfz pycharm-*.tar.gz -C /opt/
>    ```
>
>    *(**Personal note:** I would advise **against** putting PyCharm in a location that requires `sudo` permissions to write. Pick a location somewhere in your home directory instead to avoid permission problems in the future, e.g. during updates.)*
> 2. Switch to the bin subdirectory:
>
>    ```
>    cd <new_archive_folder>/pycharm-*/bin
>    ```
>
>    For example,
>
>    ```
>    cd /opt/pycharm-*/bin
>    ```
> 3. Run `pycharm.sh` from the `bin` subdirectory.

Comment: Changing "wily" to "xenial" works for ubuntu 16.04 with Pycharm 2016.2

Comment: @AlexandreNeto Yeah, I edited my answer so that the correct release name will be inserted automatically.

Comment: What's the recommended directory to install it?

Comment: +1 Good advice. I don't know if this has changed recently, but the package I found was "pycharm-community"

Comment: @JamesBradbury Where did you find that?

Comment: I typed "sudo apt-get install pych" then pressed TAB.

Comment: @JamesBradbury I don't have that. Would you mind checking the output of `apt policy pycharm-community` to see where it comes from?

Comment: Weirdly it isn't listed. I can't believe I imagined it. I also did an apt list and got no pycharm, yet it seems to be installed and running fine.

Comment: I am new to linux environment. I have installed pycharm by downloading tar.gz file. Is this like everytime I have to run pycharm.sh for using pycharm? and what about the data i have created while using it?

Comment: @SmashGuy I believe, after you ran `pycharm.sh` once, it should have added a launcher icon to your list of applications automatically. What about the data? Your projects will be stored where you decide to save them, usually `~/PyCharmProjects`.

Comment: @ByteCommander: It didn't happen as it supposed to be. I could not find the application after I closed it.

Answer (score 20):

There are a lot of resources around the web explaining that you should install it from a tar.gz or an unofficial PPA.
While using a PPA is a nice solution, I wanted to point out that Pycharm is supported by ubuntu-make.
Ubuntu-make is supported by Canonical and is a way to install any IDE you may need.

Steps are as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
umake ide pycharm
```

You can now launch pycharm from the unity launcher

Comment: If you are using a new version of Ubuntu, (16.04+ I think), the first line is not required as it is in the repositories by default.

Comment: @Mayou36 : the problem is that umake under Ubuntu 16.04 has version 16.02, but to make pycharm works you need umake version 16.03 or above. So the first line is still needed.

Answer (score 20):

PyCharm is also available as a snap package.

`sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic`

This is the Ubuntu latest iteration at an app model and any package available as a snap should be preferred. Snaps can be installed on almost all versions of Linux (as long as you've installed the snap core).

A benefit of snaps is that they update in the background, so you will always have the latest version.

> NOTE: `--classic` confinement may perform arbitrary system changes outside of the security sandbox that snaps are usually confined to, which may put your system at risk.
>
> WARNING: The publisher for this snap is [joeborg](https://github.com/joedborg), so you are trusting him.

Comment: To list installed snaps and see which version of pycharm-community was installed, run `snap list`.

Comment: To start the installed application, run `pycharm-community` in command line.

Answer (score 9):

Let [**Ubuntu Make (`umake`)**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make) do the work for you:

> Ubuntu Make is a command line tool which allows you to download the
>   latest version of popular developer tools on your installation,
>   installing it alongside all of the required dependencies [...]
>   Basically, one command to get your system ready to develop with!

1) Open the terminal (keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

2) Add ubuntu-make PPA to your system. This step is *vital* to avoid known problems ([1](https://askubuntu.com/q/770779/643185) and [2](https://askubuntu.com/q/837220/643185)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
```

3) Update the package lists from the repositories and install the latest stable version of `umake`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

4) Install PyCharm using `umake`:

If you want to install PyCharm **Community Edition**:

```
umake ide pycharm
```

If you want to install PyCharm **Professional Edition** ([license](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/buy/#edition=personal) required):

```
umake ide pycharm-professional
```

You are ready to go!

In case you change your mind, you can remove PyCharm with:

```
umake -r ide pycharm
```

Source: https://itsfoss.com/install-pycharm-ubuntu/

---

I just realized this answer is an almost duplicate of [this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/878945/643185). I am keeping it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: How to handle following message:
umake ide pycharm-professional
usage: umake ide [-h] {lighttable,visual-studio-code} ...
umake ide: error: argument framework: invalid choice: 'pycharm-professional' (choose from 'lighttable', 'visual-studio-code')

Comment: @cwhisperer Did you add ubuntu-make PPA to your system as explained in step 2? Have a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/837220/643185).