# Install PyCharm on Ubuntu 15.10 - E: Unable to locate package pycharm

Tags: apt, software-installation, 15.10, pycharm

How can I install PyCharm on Ubuntu 15.10?  When attempting to do so per  [itsfoss](http://itsfoss.com/install-pycharm-ubuntu/) **E: Unable to locate package pycharm** occurs.

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install pycharm
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package pycharm
```

On Ubuntu 15.10 running in an Oracle Virtual Box

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~$  lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```

Content of /etc/atp/sources.list is

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 15.10 _Wily Werewolf_ - Release amd64 (20151021)]/ wily main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner
```

Results of apt-get update are

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily InRelease
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates InRelease [64.4 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security InRelease [64.4 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Translation-en
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main Sources [18.9 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe Translation-en
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main Sources [31.7 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted Sources [2,854 B]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Sources [3,741 B]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Sources [7,766 B]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Sources [1,922 B]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe Sources [5,896 B]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main amd64 Packages [89.0 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse Sources [1,922 B]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [13.3 kB]
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe amd64 Packages [38.0 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main amd64 Packages [58.0 kB]
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [5,859 B]
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main i386 Packages [87.6 kB]
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted i386 Packages [13.4 kB]
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe i386 Packages [38.0 kB]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted amd64 Packages [10.9 kB]
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [6,052 B]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe amd64 Packages [28.9 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main Sources
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [5,859 B]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse Sources
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main i386 Packages [56.9 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted i386 Packages [10.8 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe Translation-en
Get:25 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe i386 Packages [28.9 kB]
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse i386 Packages [6,052 B]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe Translation-en
Fetched 701 kB in 3s (217 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: Very complete answer.  Thank you. The "GetDeb method" installs the Community edition of PyCharm.  However I want the Professional edition to edit javascript so I went with the "Download archive from jetbrains method".  Prior to running pycharm.sh I also had to install java.  To do this I added the GetDeb repository as you described then ran:

sudo apt-get install default-jre

Comment: `default-jre` is in the `main` repository, not on GetDeb. You should not add this external repository if you don't need anything from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note:** I consider most of this answer's content to be outdated. Please see [my other answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/701656/367990) for a more up to date collection of ways to install PyCharm.
>
> The original answer was:

PyCharm is not in the official repositories.

You have multiple options to install it though:

- #### Enable the GetDeb repository and install PyCharm from there:

  Run these three commands to set up the [GetDeb repository](http://www.getdeb.net/) as a software source for your system:

  ```
  echo 'deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu wily-getdeb apps' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list
  wget -q -O- http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
  sudo apt-get update
  ```

  Then you can install PyCharm Community Edition (version 5.0.1 at the date of writing):

  ```
  sudo apt-get install pycharm
  ```

  You will automatically receive package updates through GetDeb, no need to update PyCharm manually or with its own updater.
- #### Enable a PPA and install PyCharm from there:

  Please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/706595/367990) of [Luís de Sousa](https://askubuntu.com/users/177437/lu%c3%ads-de-sousa) for a PPA option.

  You will also receive automatic package updates through the PPA, as soon as its owner uploads a new version (which is not as reliable and fast as GetDeb usually...)
- #### Download the compressed archive from the official JetBrains site:

  On the official homepage of JetBrains, the developing company of PyCharm, there is a [download section](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) offering both the free Community Edition and a 30-day-trial-version of the Professional Edition, both for Windows, OS X and Linux.

  Direct download link for the  [latest PyCharm version (free Community Edition) for Linux](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/download_thanks.jsp?edition=comm&os=linux).

  The [official installation instructions for Linux](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/installation_instructions.jsp?os=linux) are those:

  > - Copy the `pycharm-*.tar.gz` to an empty directory (make sure you have rw permissions for that directory)
  > - Unpack the `pycharm-*.tar.gz` using the following command:
  >
  >   ```
  >   tar xfz pycharm-*.tar.gz
  >   ```
  > - Remove the pycharm-*.tar.gz to save disk space (optional)
  > - Run `pycharm.sh` from the bin subdirectory
  >
  > **NOTE:** PyCharm on Linux doesn't need special installation or running any installation script. It runs out of the `pycharm-*.tar.gz`

  You don't get any automatic package updates this way, but will rely in PyCharms internal update mechanism.

My personal favourite is **GetDeb**, but you may chose which one you prefer.

Answer (score 4):

PyCharm is not available from the official Ubuntu repositories, you must retrieve it from a third party PPA. Therefore, before asking `apt-get` to install the package, you must first make it aware of the correct PPA. Run the following in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mystic-mirage/pycharm
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you can install PyCharm:

```
sudo apt-get install pycharm
```

Comment: it does not work for me (ubuntu 17.04) - the mystic-mirage seems to have been removed? getting 404