# How do I install and use PyCharm without having to use a terminal?

Tags: pycharm

Unlike the previous [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file), the `tar.gz` of PyCharm or SmartGit does not have `make` or `./configure`.

I always open terminal at `bin` and type `./pycharm.sh`, which leaves the terminal open while I'm using the application.

How can I just click the PyCharm application icon and run it without a terminal in Ubuntu Desktop?

Comment: @kos // but my question is not only for PyCharm although the answer is leaded so. It would be good to edit answer rather than addressing whole question direction.

Comment: But it does depend very much on what the software is. The most general method is `./configure; make; make install`.

Comment: Where is this "PyCharm application icon" located?

Comment: Ok, but then your question is duplicate of this one: http://askubuntu.com/q/13758/338915. Since  you received an answer addressing PyCharm (which you accepted) and hg8 also pointed you to the general method already I thought it was better to rephrase it like that. If you're not comfortable with this then I'm sorry about it, and you can roll back the edit if you want, but then I'll have to vote to close it as a duplicate of the other. I think it's more useful to keep it as it stands.

Comment: You're welcome. Remember that you can also upvote the answer you accept if you find them useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install PyCharm on Unbuntu 15.10 - E: Unable to locate package pycharm](http://askubuntu.com/questions/706573/install-pycharm-on-unbuntu-15-10-e-unable-to-locate-package-pycharm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set up PyCharm to launch from the Launcher?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/391439/how-can-i-set-up-pycharm-to-launch-from-the-launcher)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PyCharm (like Intellij Idea and other JetBrain products) have a built in function to create desktop icon :

**Tools** > **Create desktop Entry**.

Once done you will find PyCharm in your Ubuntu Dash.

Comment: Thanks, and how about other `tar.gz` -> unpack -> `./something.sh` programs like SmartGit?

Comment: For this, take a look here : [How can I create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](http://askubuntu.com/q/13758/338915) **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, the answer by hg8 is your best option. In general, to run a command in the background, use `./pycharm.sh &`. Note that any output to standard output and standard error will still show up in this window, so it may not be ideal to keep using the window for other commands.

If you have already started the process, you can still close the terminal window by first pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to pause the process followed by `bg`, which will continue the process in the background. You can then close the terminal window without terminating the application.