# PyCharm/IntelliJ update error under Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: updates, java, intellij, pycharm

I am getting a **java.io.FileNotFoundException** when trying to update PyCharm/IntelliJ:

1. Ubuntu 16.04.
2. Installed PyCharm as per **GetDeb** in https://askubuntu.com/a/701656/631904.
3. It says it wants to update
   from PyCharm 2016.3.2 to 2016.3.3.  It says I do not have write
   access to `/usr/share/pycharm`.  So I run `sudo pycharm`. After
   **Downloading Patch File** and "Some conflicts were found in the
   installation area" where its "Solution" is "IGNORE" I click **Proceed**.

Get "Failed to Apply Patch":

```
Temp. directory: /root/.PyCharmCE2016.3/system/tmp/patch-update

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/.PyCharmCE2016.3/system/log/idea.updater.files.tmp.0/temp.tmp.1/bin/pycharm.png (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at com.intellij.updater.Utils.newFileInputStream(Utils.java:260)
at com.intellij.updater.UpdateAction.doApply(UpdateAction.java:65)
at com.intellij.updater.PatchAction.apply(PatchAction.java:201)
at com.intellij.updater.Patch.lambda$apply$2(Patch.java:323)
at com.intellij.updater.Patch.forEach(Patch.java:372)
at com.intellij.updater.Patch.apply(Patch.java:321)
at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.apply(PatchFileCreator.java:84)
at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.apply(PatchFileCreator.java:76)
at com.intellij.updater.Runner.doInstall(Runner.java:303)
at com.intellij.updater.Runner.lambda$install$0(Runner.java:272)
at com.intellij.updater.SwingUpdaterUI.lambda$doPerform$4(SwingUpdaterUI.java:190)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I think IntelliJ is involved because that is a default for the editor settings.

Comment: I have yet to see a full-fledged and up-to-date (Java) IDE in a packaged form. Use http://askubuntu.com/a/701656/75166 to install it like the rest of us and you will do fine.

Comment: I uninstalled and followed advice to fetch & install "manually", instead of GetDeb repository route.  It is now successfully at 3.3.