# Is it safe to install using snap --classic?

Tags: snap, pycharm

I wanted to install Pycharm Community edition using snap with the following command:

`sudo snap install pycharm-community`

Unfortunately, I got the following error message:

```
error: This revision of snap "pycharm-community" was published using classic confinement and thus may perform arbitrary system changes outside of the security sandbox that snaps are usually confined to, which may put your system at risk.
If you understand and want to proceed repeat the command including
--classic.
```

**My question is:** is it safe to proceed and install it using `--classic` as they suggest? What are the risks of doing so? (i.e what kind of "arbitrary system changes" can happen?) And lastly, has anyone tried it and did everything go well?

I previously installed IntelliJ IDEA a few weeks ago and didn't get this problem.
Of course, there are certainly other ways to install it, but I found snap to be a convenient tool as then I just need to type the name of the program in the terminal to launch it.

Comment: See [What are the dangers of using snap's classic confinement?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/493033/103151)

Comment: Unrelated to the question in your title, I'd personally recommend installing the JetBrains Toolbox and managing all IDEs through that. See [PyCharm by JetBrains installation](https://askubuntu.com/q/701618/367990) for instructions and other alternative installation methods.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer and tips. From the other post it seems that the risk is limited as snap store checks it before it goes online, so I might just try `snap install --classic`.

Answer (score 1):

Short Ans: YES! IT IS COMPLETELY SAFE.

---

Long Ans:

Source: https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement

> #### What is Snap Confinement?
>
> A snap’s confinement level is the degree of isolation it has from your
> system. There are three levels of snap confinement:
>
> - Strict
>
>   Used by the majority of snaps. Strictly confined snaps run in complete isolation, up to a minimal access level that’s deemed always
>   safe. Consequently, strictly confined snaps can not access your files,
>   network, processes or any other system resource without requesting
>   specific access via an interface.
> - Classic
>
>   Allows access to your system’s resources in much the same way traditional packages do. To safeguard against abuse, publishing a
>   classic snap requires manual approval, and installation requires the
>   `--classic` command line argument.
> - Devmode
>
>   A special mode for snap creators and developers. A devmode snap runs as a strictly confined snap with full access to system resources,
>   and produces debug output to identify unspecified interfaces.
>   Installation requires the `--devmode` command line argument. Devmode
>   snaps cannot be released to the stable channel, do not appear in
>   search results, and do not automatically refresh.

I think now you understand that to install mostly code IDE(s) through command line interface you have to manually give confinement permission to them with `--classic` as they have to access files and folders in different spaces located on your machine to update/change/modify etc.
But if you install them from GUI software centers then they already have the confinement permission with them and if you install them with browser's help by downloading there `.deb` files then also they have the same confinement permission so either way they are going to need the `--classic` permission no matter through what method you install them.
eg:

```
sudo snap install code --classic

sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic

sudo snap install sublime-text --classic
```

What you'll see when you type `snap find code`:

[image]

What you'll see if you try to install packages from software centers:

[image]